# Duplicate Sheet with Name of Cell Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am wondering if there is a way to duplicate a sheet I am working on and assigning that new duplicate sheet a name based on a cell value in the original sheet?

Right now I am simply using a script/button to clear content of cell values to start a new stock order (see below)

```
function newSalesOrder() {
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ranges = ["StockOrder!B4", "StockOrder!E8", "StockOrder!D9","StockOrder!A12:B41"];
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        activeSheet.getRange(ranges[i]).clearContent();
    }
}
```

So I would like to add the ability to duplicate the StockOrder! sheet, rename it to the Purchase Order Number value in Cell C4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, all you need to do is:

- Save the content of a given cell into a String variable

This one is a bit tricky, the hierarchy in Google sheets is: SpreadSheet: Sheet: Range: Cell. So what you need to do to get the value of Cell C4 is:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Insert ID here');
  var name = ss.getName();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Insert Sheet Name Here');
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,4); 
  var newSheetName = range.getValue();
```

Of course, you do not need to use openById or getSheetByName methods. You can use getActiveSheet() or whatever you like.

- Create a new sheet whose title is the saved String variable

  `var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheetName);`

Hope this is gonna help:)

Comment: Fantastic Thanks! I'll give this a try and let you know how it worked out!

Comment: Hello, I have tried the script but am getting errors.  I'll try to make a Public version of the sheets when I have some time, perhaps that will help.